# Netherland IND waiting times for Residence card for family of EU citizen RC (EU Directive EC/38/2004)

Tags: eu, netherlands, eu-citizens

Any experience or idea on time it takes for Immidiate family members (dependent parents) of EU citizen's residence card application after you submit it at IND office?

Also called as Verification against EU laws.

Cheers

Anybody have any recent experience on timescale from application to approval / further clarification?
Thanks

Comment: Just call them. I have another case and it took two months to get new card

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any suggestion on their phone number/Email? As general phoneline 0880****430 seems to be always busy, with wait time exceeding more than 20-30 mins at a times. Thanks